# Zend Framework - how to upload posts to my blog?

Tags: zend-framework

I want to be able to create ready to publish blog posts on my desktop and then upload them to a blog I've created with ZF.

(similar to Wordpress from what I've read).

Looking for suggestions on how that is best implemented?

Thanks, -km

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself comfortable with [Zend Documentation for xmlRPC](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.xmlrpc.html).
That is the way it is done in Wordpress (and how it should be done in Zend Framework -- I think).

This [Wordpress source code of xmlrpc.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/xmlrpc.php) shows how it is working in Wordpress. Didn't found any examples for Zend, but it should work out (as it is also just php).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. If there are any examples out there that would really be a bonus!